# NSClipView ghosting, artifacts, trails on setDrawsBackground:NO

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm trying to get NSClipView to either draw a clear background (set the color to clear results in a black box), or no background at all. Drawing no background results in ghosting artifacts. Anyway to get this to draw no background without the artifacts???

The NSClipView is contained inside an NSBox subclass. An NSTextView is contained inside the NSClipView. It's basically an attempt at rolling my own NSTextField. I need to be able to draw a custom background and included subviews such as buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trails behavior is noted in the documentation of [NSClipView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSClipView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If the clip view is contained in a NSScrollView the documentation suggests calling setDrawsBackground: on the scroll view instead.

You could also try setting the background color of the scroll view to the clear color, assuming that the clip view is in a scroll view.

If the clip view is not in a scroll view then you might want to explain what the view hierarchy is like, and any code relavent to its construction.

Comment: The clip view is contained in an NSBox. I'm drawing my own background so I've set it's fillColor to clearColor. I've got an NSTextView inside the clip view.